# jQuery cookie and toggle()

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

When the element `h4` is clicked, I would like to `.toggle()` the `.mChatBodyFix` but I would like to toggle the `$.cookie` to either be `yes` or `no`

```
    $('.cat h4').not('.mChatOpts span').click(function(){
        $('.mChatBodyFix').toggle();
        $.cookie('chat', 'yes', {expires:1});
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$.cookie('chat', $.cookie('chat')=='yes'?"no":"yes", {expires:1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$('.cat h4').not('.mChatOpts span').click(function(){
    $('.mChatBodyFix').toggle();
    var myCookie = $.cookie('chat')=='yes'?"no":"yes";
    $.cookie('chat', myCookie, {expires:1});
});
```